# What's the best choice for this rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

I have a model called `User`, and another called `Run`. Each user have many runs. Duration and distance are attributes of Run.

I want to display on the user page, the sum of the distance and duration of his runs.

I'm not sure if this sum, i.e., total distance and total duration should be attributes of the user, or if it's should be calculated on the `ViewProfileController` just in order to display it on his profile.

What would be the correct practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum of the user runs should be a method in the user model, because it's specific to each user.

Also, a best practice is to have skinny controllers and have fat models.

Comment: +1, would add more explanation: because, if you want those values at other view/controller/worker, you don't need to calculate them again, they are a kind of User attribute. For example, you want to send a special email for users with distance_runned>1000, instead of do all the calculations, just use User model to get those users.